# You have an existing certificate that has exactly the same domains or certificate name you requested and isn't close to expiry

Tags: ssl, https

When I am using this command to renew my website certificate:

```
/data/docker/nginx/volume/conf/conf/conf.d/cert/example.com/certbot-auto certonly -d '*.example.com' \
--no-self-upgrade \
--manual --preferred-challenges dns \
--server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```

shows information like this:

```
You have an existing certificate that has exactly the same domains or certificate name you requested and isn't close to expiry.
(ref: /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com-0001.conf)

What would you like to do?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: Keep the existing certificate for now
2: Renew & replace the cert (may be subject to CA rate limits)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel):
```

should I replace the certificate? My certificate will expire less than 10 days, are not close to expire? how many days are treated as closed?

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting the same error when updating my SSL.
Here is a trick I use for the `collabora.xx.com` subdomain.
Step 1: `cd /etc/letsencrypt/renewal` and delete the **.conf** file related to the domain/subdomain in my case its `collabora.xx.com.conf`
Step 2:  Run the following command

```
certbot certonly --webroot -w /www/html/sites/letsencrypt -d collabora.xx.com
certbot certonly  -d collabora.xx.com
systemctl stop nginx
certbot certonly  -d collabora.xx.com
systemctl restart nginx
```

remember `collabora.xx.com` is a subdomain in my case.